# why is my very easy piece of jQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm very hard wondering why this code doens't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#text-heading").slideDown("slow");

});
```

I want  this to work as following: when I enter the page, the selected div should drop downwards, but for some dark reason this doensn't happen. jQuery is called right, I did a namecheck and all that I'm feeling really stupid.

Comment: Can we see your HTML?

Comment: `#text-heading` needs to be hidden before you can slide it down.

Comment: Are you sure you are hiding it in the first place before slideDown?

Comment: How is the element hidden in the first place?  `display`?  `opacity`?  Some other means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#text-heading")` needs to be hidden first before [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) will do anything.

Try this:

```
$("#text-heading").hide().slideDown('slow');
```

Comment: Though, it would make more sense for the element to be hidden via style in the initial markup than to actively hide it and then slide it down.

Comment: @BasdeVries: Well, `slideDown` _un-hides_ it.  So, it has to be hidden first.  Otherwise what exactly do you expect `slideDown` to do?  Note that you can have it be hidden by default via CSS before executing any JavaScript.

Comment: from the top to it's position would seem more logically to me, but thanks!

Comment: @BasdeVries - You can add `$("#text-heading").slideUp()` before the `slideDown()` in order to ensure it is hidden if you don't want to use `hide()`.